# Where is this unknown column in my MYSQL DB?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to find out what or where this "unknown column" error is coming from. To my untrained eyes, the code looks ok from a syntax point of view. Obviously I'm missing something though..I get an error 1054.

Here is the database (it's only a little one). Can someone please tell what is going on?
The error refers to the INSERT INTO statement for the `enrolment` table.

-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BR000726910
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `BR000726910` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BR000726910
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `BR000726910` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BR000726910`.`school`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BR000726910`,`school` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910`.`school` (
  `SchoolName` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SchoolName`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `school` (`SchoolName`, `Address`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email` ) 
VALUES ('Heartbreak_High', '46_Ratloch_Road_Craiglang', '0882346000', 'PimpZ@Hotrods.com' );

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BR000726910`.`student`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BR000726910`,`student` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910`.`student` (
  `StudentID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `MiddleInitial` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `ResidentialAddress` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` DATE NULL,
  `DateOfEnrolment` DATE NULL,
  `Gender` CHAR(1) NULL,
  `school_SchoolName` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StudentID`),
  INDEX `fk_student_school1_idx` (`school_SchoolName` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_student_school1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`school_SchoolName`)
    REFERENCES `BR000726910`.`school` (`SchoolName`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `ResidentialAddress`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `DateOfEnrolment`,
`Gender`) VALUES ('10002340', 'Benjamin', 'J', 'Roberts', '0476066591', 'Bermuda_Triangle', 'Goober@Ringworm.com', '1937-06-21', '1788-01-26', 'M' );
INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `ResidentialAddress`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `DateOfEnrolment`,
`Gender`) VALUES ('18831492', 'John', 'F', 'Kennedy', '0418812345', 'Arlington_National_Cemetary', 'conspiracy@theory.com', '1931-06-04', '2021-02-21', 'M' );
INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `ResidentialAddress`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `DateOfEnrolment`,
`Gender`) VALUES ('10110001', 'Homer', 'J', 'Simpson', '0400000001', '12_Donut_Street,Springfield', 'mmmdonuts@greedyguts.com', '1901-01-01', '2021-03-21', 'M' );
INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `ResidentialAddress`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `DateOfEnrolment`,
`Gender`) VALUES ('14921883', 'Jesus', 'H', 'Christ', '043142000', '01_Big_Bang_Avenue_Universe', 'praytoday@foryoursoul.com', '0001-12-25', '1238-09-20', 'M' );
INSERT INTO `student` (`StudentID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `ResidentialAddress`, `Email`, `DateOfBirth`, `DateOfEnrolment`,
`Gender`) VALUES ('19876543', 'Hannibal', 'K', 'Lecter', '0433666999', '02_Dank_Cell_CrazyTown', 'favabeans@chianti.com', '1949-03-27', '1111-12-13', 'M' );


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BR000726910`.`teacher`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BR000726910`,`teacher` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910`.`teacher` (
  `TeacherID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `MiddleInitial` VARCHAR(5) NULL,
  `Surname` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
  `school_SchoolName` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TeacherID`),
  INDEX `fk_teacher_school1_idx` (`school_SchoolName` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_teacher_school1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`school_SchoolName`)
    REFERENCES `BR000726910`.`school` (`SchoolName`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `teacher` (`TeacherID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `Surname`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`)
VALUES ('42424242', 'Vlad', 'D', 'Impaler', 'Beachbunny@wrongendofthestick.com', '082814444' );
INSERT INTO `teacher` (`TeacherID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `Surname`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`)
VALUES ('48241206', 'Pablo', 'S', 'Cabar', 'DrugNazi@sinoloacartel.com', '1800008110' );
INSERT INTO `teacher` (`TeacherID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `Surname`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`)
VALUES ('40801603', 'Tee', 'N', 'Wolf', 'dogbreath@hairloss.com', '0403020100' );
INSERT INTO `teacher` (`TeacherID`, `FirstName`, `MiddleInitial`, `Surname`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber`)
VALUES ('45677654', 'Wile', 'E', 'Coyote', 'winnerwinner@chickendinner.com', '0413579111' );


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BR000726910`.`subject`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BR000726910`,`subject` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910`.`subject` (
  `SubjectCode` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  `TeacherID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `SubjectDescription` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  `CostofSubject` DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `CourseDuration` INT(3) NULL,
  `NumberAssessmentItems` INT(3) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SubjectCode`),
  INDEX `fk_subject_teacher1_idx` (`TeacherID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_teacher1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TeacherID`)
    REFERENCES `BR000726910`.`teacher` (`TeacherID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `subject` (`SubjectCode`, `TeacherID`, `SubjectDescription`, `CostofSubject`, `CourseDuration`, `NumberAssessmentItems` )
VALUES ('WEBSQL001', '42424242', 'A searing treatise on the seismic shifts taking place in the world of database stuff', '1200.00', '12', '3' );
INSERT INTO `subject` (`SubjectCode`, `TeacherID`, `SubjectDescription`, `CostofSubject`, `CourseDuration`, `NumberAssessmentItems` )
VALUES ('PYTHON101', '48241206', 'A charming voyage of self discovery looking at a snake coming of age', '1955.06', '12', '2' );
INSERT INTO `subject` (`SubjectCode`, `TeacherID`, `SubjectDescription`, `CostofSubject`, `CourseDuration`, `NumberAssessmentItems` )
VALUES ('BVHL90210', '40801603', 'The comatose idiocy of millenials trying to adult', '1000.00', '12', '56' );
INSERT INTO `subject` (`SubjectCode`, `TeacherID`, `SubjectDescription`, `CostofSubject`, `CourseDuration`, `NumberAssessmentItems` )
VALUES ('STRP00001', '45677654', 'Learn the exciting art of Latvian pole dancing', '49.94', '12', '1' );


-- -----------------------------------------------
-- Table `BR000726910`.`enrolment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `BR000726910`,`enrolment` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BR000726910`.`enrolment` (
  `Grade` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
  `ResultForStudent` INT(3) NOT NULL,
  `DateOfGrade` DATE NULL,
  `student_StudentID` INT(8) NOT NULL,
  `subject_SubjectCode` VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Grade`),
    INDEX `fk_enrolment_student1_idx` (`student_StudentID` ASC) VISIBLE,
    INDEX `fk_enrolment_subject1_idx` (`subject_SubjectCode` ASC) VISIBLE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_enrolment_student1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`student_StudentID`)
    REFERENCES `BR000726910`.`student` (`StudentID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_enrolment_subject1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subject_SubjectCode`)
    REFERENCES `BR000726910`.`subject` (`SubjectCode`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade`, `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('CRED', '78', '1981-03-03', '10002340', 'BVHL90210');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade`, `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('FAIL', '32', '1981-09-15' , '10110001', 'PYTHON101');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade`, `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('PASS', '61', '1981-11-08' , '14921883', 'WEBSQL001');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('CRED', '71', '1981-09-15' , '18831492', 'STRP00001');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade`, `StudentID`, `SubjectCode` )
VALUES ('CRED', '74', '1981-09-15' , '19876543', 'BVHL90210');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('DIST' , '98', '1981-09-15', '10002340', 'PYTHON101');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('DIST', '91', '1981-09-15' , '10110001', 'WEBSQL001');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('CRED', '75', '1988-08-15', '14921883', 'STRP00001');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('PASS', '63', '1981-09-15', '18831492', 'BVHL90210');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('FAIL', '12', '1981-09-14', '19876543', 'PYTHON101');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('CRED', '80', '1981-09-15', '10002340', 'WEBSQL001');
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade`, `StudentID`, `SubjectCode` )
VALUES ('CRED', '80', '1981-09-15', '10110001', 'STRP00001' );
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('DIST', '98', '1981-09-15', '14921883', 'BVHL90210' );
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('DIST', '98', '1981-09-15', '18831492', 'PYTHON101' );
INSERT INTO `enrolment` (`Grade`, `ResultForStudent`, `DateOfGrade` , `StudentID`, `SubjectCode`)
VALUES ('DIST', '98', '1981-09-15', '19876543', 'WEBSQL001' );



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Can you post the *exact* error?

Comment: Hint: You do not have a column called precisely `StudentID`.

Comment: Mysql <> SQL server - please correct your tags

Comment: Please post any errors verbatim

Comment: maybe you've found it already - not sure how you got this error when it seems like the above is from `mysqldump`, but the inserts into `enrollment` reference `StudentId`, but the table definition has `student_StudentId`.